How to send a base64 string or UTF-8 MemoryStream object to Symantec Protection Engine (SPE) in AWS
All the examples I've seen show files being sent to the SPE AWS Virus Scanner api but I have a base64 string or my code has converted this string to a UTF-8 MemoryStream object.  The previously implemented Symantec dll had no issues sending this MemoryStream via 512 byte blocks.
In the code below, the myMemoryStream variable was the fileStream variable in the sample code snippet.
When the call is made and the result is parsed, it returns an error: Unsupported Media Type.
Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?
File code reference snippet:
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
Uri scanUrl = new Uri(hostUrl + "/api/Scan");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
using (var fileStream = fileToAdd.OpenReadStream())
{
    var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    form.Add(streamContent, "documents", fileToAdd.FileName);
    form.Add(new StringContent("NONE"), "composite");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Prefer", "respond-async");
    response = await client.PostAsync(scanUrl, form);

}
My new code:
//resumeFile is a string in base64
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resumeFile);
MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
...
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
Uri scanUrl = new Uri(hostUrl + "/api/Scan");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var streamContent = new StreamContent(myMemoryStream);
streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
form.Add(streamContent, "documents", fileName);
form.Add(new StringContent("NONE"), "composite");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Prefer", "respond-async");
response = await client.PostAsync(scanUrl, form);

dynamic parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

I tried changing the MediaTypeHeaderValue to text/plain.
Couldn't interrogate the contents of the "parsed" variable to determine if it could tell me more about what was wrong with the call.
What I was expecting was the code to at least give me some better feedback than "Unsupported Media Type".  Would be nice if it told me what it found.

It's not clear to me why you've taken an example which uploads a single multipart, and changed it to code which uploads the "documents" and "composite" parts? Yet you're not specifying "uploadTo"? Where to 512 byte blocks come into all of this?

If you run the "File code reference snippet" (appropriately fixed so that form isn't unused, etc), does that produce an error?

@canton7 the "snippet" code is from another teams implementation of the scanner and they have the file downloaded to process.  My process only has access to the base64 string that represents the file.  So running that code is not an option, I was using that code as a template.  Reviewing the SPE documentation it says I can replace the filestream contents with an existing memorystream object, which I have done.  I've been trying to figure out why it is returning Unsupported media type.  Is this memory stream not application/octet-stream.  Does it need to be in UTF8, base64 or byte[] array?

@canton7, also, the previous Symantec implementation was using their DLL and not AWS.  The method calls was taking in 512byte blocks as part of that process.  This new process requires the entire data stream to be sent with the requests.

"Reviewing the SPE documentation it says I can replace the filestream contents with an existing memorystream object, which I have done" -- I don't see any code which does this. Have you done it correctly? I'm not sure where Symantec comes in to be honest -- there's nothing in your code which does anything with 512-bytes blocks

And again, it's not clear to me why you're not using the example from the documentation. If you run the "File code reference snippet" (appropriately fixed so that form isn't unused, etc), does that produce an error? Also, in your second snippet, you're not specifying "uploadTo"?

"Does it need to be in UTF8, base64 or byte[] array?" -- a stream is a series of bytes. UTF-8 is a way of encoding text as bytes, so that makes no senses in this context (you're not working with text). Base64 is a way of representing bytes as text: that's also not relevant (nowhere do the docs say you encode your binary using base64). A byte[] is an array of bytes (a bit like a stream, but the length is known upfront and you can access random elements): you can wrap a byte[] in a stream (using MemoryStream)

@canton7 the AWS Symantec scanner uri is the endpoint of this call.  I've added the full blown sample code snippet as well as my updated code block showing how the  myMemoryStream variable is populated.  Ignore the 512byte block as that was for reference to what was working locally using the symantec virus scan dll.

"resumeFile is a string in base64" -- so why are you using Encoding.UTF8 to turn that base64 string into bytes? Use Convert.FromBase64String

@canton7 when I change the byte[] byteArray line to, byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(resumeFile);  That returns an error -- "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."   I've used that payload many times before and have even run that base64 string thru a validator.

What's the length of resultFile? It should be a multiple of 4

21,484 characters.  I found a different online decoder, pasted the contents and it returned binary.  To confirm, I removed the trailing == and the first character and it said invalid... putting those characters back, it decoded again. Debugging the program returned the same length.

I was finally able to get my scanner to work. A combination of how the http request was built and working with the scanner team, they found the base64 stream I was using to be "invalid" or corrupt enough that it returned an error.  Sorry for the delayed response as I went out on leave on 10/17 and last week made the code breakthrough.  Thanks for all your help @canton7, your time and answers helped.
